# Conditional formatting with element selector

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to highlight all links that do not have a `href` set, or if it is blank. I wrote the following: http://jsfiddle.net/nSMEf/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.green').attr("href") == "" || typeof $('.green').attr("href") === 'undefined'){
      $('.green').attr('class', 'yellow');
  }

  if ($('.blue').attr("href") == "" || typeof $('.blue').attr("href") === 'undefined'){
       $('.blue').attr('class', 'yellow');
  }
});
```

I noticed that the if statement seemed to apply only on which link came first, and all the following links would be styled the same. The second "blue" group is the same as the first but with the order switched.

My approach clearly isn't right. Is it possible to have the yellow class applied conditionally (based if the href is blank or not there) on each element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would this help

```
    $("a").each(function(){

       if(!($(this).attr("href")) || $(this).attr("href") == "") {
          $(this).addClass("yellow");
       }       
    });
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nSMEf/3/

Editing above code according to suggestion in comments

```
 $("a").each(function(){
    var self = $(this).attr("href");
    if(!(self) || self == "") {
        $(this).addClass("yellow");
    }        
});
```

Comment: The only comment I'd make is that it *might* make sense to cache the `$(this).attr('href')`. Otherwise, +1 more efficient than where I was going. =)

Comment: Learn a new thing everyday :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/5ehtZ/  || http://jsfiddle.net/5ehtZ/2/

**code**

```
$("a").each(function(){
    //do something with the element here.
    if (!($(this).attr("href")) || $(this).attr("href") == ""){
        // now blue and green diff is not needed because you append yellow if they are empty.
         $(this).attr('class', 'yellow');
    }

});
​
```

Comment: :( undefined became undefined

Comment: @MiaDiLorenzo aha will update it The only resin I removed t because I thought href will always be there with definitive object. :) and done cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Wait.. What?

Wouldn't a jQuery selector do the job?

$('.blue[href=""]').addClass('yellow');

Comment: How do you cover the case where href is undefined (Number 3)?

Comment: $('.blue:not([href])').addClass('yellow')
Fizzle is probably faster in most cases than looping. :P

Comment: I'm dense. How do you combine [href=""] with :not([href])?

Comment: A comma? $('.blue[href=""],.blue:not([href])').addClass('yellow');